# How to fetch record with string building query has a column heading in gujarati?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing issue in my below string build query. When I execute the query, it prints in column heading as `??????`. I want column heading in Gujarati, with below query (string build query) only.

```
declare  @Query1 varchar(max)

SET @Query1 ='
select RefNo as N'આવક સંદર્ભ'
from Test where 1=1'
print (@Query1)
exec (@Query1)
```

if i write below simple query and execute than it's work perfect and my column heading display in Gujarati well.

```
select RefNo as N'આવક સંદર્ભ'
from Test where 1=1.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i used sql server.

Comment: Try `declare  @Query1 nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: And perhaps `SET @Query1 = N'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nvarchar()`:

```
declare  @Query1 nvarchar(max);

SET @Query1 = N'
select RefNo as N''આવક સંદર્''
from Test where 1=1'
print (@Query1)
exec (@Query1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9dc3fa6fe921da8b4787aa64700b782) is a db<>fiddle.

I do recommend that you write the query like this:

```
declare  @Query1 nvarchar(max);

SET @Query1 = N'
select RefNo as [આવક સંદર્]
from Test
where 1=1'
print(@Query1)
exec sp_executesql @Query1;
```

For two reasons:

1. Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names.
2. Use `sp_executesql` as a general rule, so you can always pass in parameters if you want.